# множественное удаление из таблицы на php laravel

Tags: php, база-данных, laravel, table

Есть таблица, в которой отображены пользователи БД. Возле каждого пользователя `checkbox`, когда `checkbox = true` мы можем удалить пользователя из БД, нажав на кнопку удалить.

Как сделать возможность множественного выделения пользователей?

Контроллер удаления:

```
public function destroy($id) {
         DB::delete('delete from users where id = ?',[$id]);
         echo "Record deleted successfully.<br/>";
         echo '<a href="/reason">Click Here</a> to go back.';
     }
 }
```

Кнопка удаления:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-dark">
    <a href = 'delete/{{$user->id }}'>
        Delete
    </a>
</button>
```

Comment: так вопрос в выделении или удалении?